# Can I inject USB Power Delivery through a hub or some other device?

Tags: usb, usb-hub, usb-power-delivery

I've ordered some [computer speakers](https://us.creative.com/p/speakers/creative-pebble-v3) that are powered via USB type C. They *can* run off normal USB power but will sound better if they can get extra juice from USB PD. Unfortunately my ageing PC does not support PD on its ports. I have two options:

1. Use a separate PD power supply (like a phone charger) and attach the speakers via aux cable.
2. Run the speakers through a powered USB hub that can act as a USB PD supply.

I'd prefer the second option because then I can rely on the built-in DAC which is probably better than my onboard sound adapter. Well, the difference is probably going to be small anyway, but still.

But I'm not sure if this is actually possible. I can find some USB hubs that have PD mentioned, but it's not clear if they actually supply the power themselves or expect it to come from the upstream computer.

Is this actually possible, or does the PD need to come from the upstream computer? Or perhaps the USB connection is unusable while PD is active, so I'd need to use the Aux cable anyway?

Comment: Where does it say that USB-PD is required for these speakers?  The speakers are rated for a 10 watt power adapter and that is within the specs of USB 2.0, USB-A, and USB-BC.  USB-C and USB-PD are not required for 10 watts.  My nearly decade old MacBook can provide the power these speakers require from it's USB-A ports, 5V @ 2A.  I'm thinking you assume too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hub has its own power-supply it will take of the PD by itself.
If it doesn't have a power-supply it will just pass on whatever is coming from the computer and (possibly) even remove the PD if the computer supplied it.

Use of PD is independent of the actual USB data-signal on the same connector so you won't need that AUX cable. (And with the AUX cable you won't get any benefit of the build-in DAC in the speakers anyway. AUX only supports analog signal.)

Comment: But... do they _exist_? I've been looking at all kinds of USB hubs for a while now and they're either PD-passthrough (that is, they are powered by PD themselves), or they take a separate power input but don't offer PD.

Comment: @Vilx- They do exist but they are pretty rare. PD is more or less standard on USB docking stations as these need a bigger and more complex power supply anyway. In pure hubs it is extra complexity/cost so most manufacturers don’t bother.

Comment: Rare is right. I've yet to see a single one. Closest I came to was some industrial PD injector which costs about 100$ and I still have no idea if they ship to my end of the world. Considering that the speakers themselves were about 35€, this is a bit of an overkill. Same goes for docking stations; I doubt I'll get anything good for less than 100$. I guess I'll go the charger+aux cable route. That's kinda what I was expecting anyway when I started to look for speakers.

Comment: @Vilx- USB-C docs wil set you back about $150 if you want a good one. Personally I've got good experience with the Dell D3100 (about $150) and the D6000 (about $200). And you have to be careful with DisplayLink drivers for the dock if your computer also has Thunderbolt. Older versions of the DisplayLink and Thunderbolt drivers don't play well together. Make sure TB drivers are current before installing the newest DisplayLink drivers.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. Frankly, I don't even care about any other features of the dock. As I said, I have a desktop PC with a plethora of ports by default (and a dedicated gaming VGA), so $150 is even less justifiable.

Answer (score 0):

> Use a separate PD power supply (like a phone charger) and attach the
> speakers via aux cable.

That's likely your best option.

> Run the speakers through a powered USB hub that can act as a USB PD
> supply.

These are not cheap, for how much they cost you might be better off buying different speakers.  I also searched long and hard for a powered hub that could provide plenty of power to USB-C ports, and eventually found this: https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/owc-thunderbolt-hub

That Thunderbolt/USB-C hub is complete overkill because the USB-PD capable USB-C port is rated for 60 watts.  I'm not seeing where this speaker set requires USB-PD, and USB-PD is not required to supply the 10 watts the speakers are rated to draw.  I too have an old computer that lacks USB-C (I bought that USB-C hub to add USB-C to the computer) but I'm fairly certain the USB-A ports on the computer are rated to supply the 2 amps these speakers are rated to draw.  It's an older MacBook Pro and Apple made MacBook Pro models capable of 2.1 amps from their USB-A ports, likely to allow for faster charging of their popular iPhones and iPads.  Check the specs on your computer because the USB-A ports might be rated to supply 2 amps, it's not unheard of on "aging" computers that lack USB-C.

What concerns me about the speakers is that they include a USB-C/female to USB-A/male adapter that is in violation of the USB specs.  That makes me wonder what other USB specs they ignored.  Do the speakers make the proper requests for power as required by the USB spec?  Or do they not bother asking nicely and just draw power based on the position of that switch on the back?  I'm suspicious and so it may be wise to only plug the speakers into a USB power brick rated for 10 watts or more.

I know it's been a while since this question has been asked but I answer in case someone comes across this like I did while looking for answers to a similar question.  I also offer this answer to give possible alternatives to whatever solution has been found in the time that has passed since the question was asked.

Comment: Hi! You managed to answer before I could. :) As for needing PD - isn't that what "USB-C 10W" means? Standard USB can only supply 2.5W (5V, 0.5A), and for 10W you need PD. Anyways, I did get the speakers, and a separate power adapter with PD and... there was no difference in sound no matter how I connected them. So I just plug them directly into a USB2 port and be done with it. I barely run them at half volume anyway, so I guess I was worried for nothing. :)

Comment: Also, what about the adapter is in violation of the specs? Is it not allowed to make USB-C/female to USB-A/male adapters? There are USB-C/male to USB-A/male cables, and USB-C/male to USB-C/male cables, so why not an adapter that can change from one to the other?

Comment: "USB-C 10W" means it's not suited to USB-C hosts that are rated for only 7.5 watts.  The USB-C spec requires that USB-C hosts provide 7.5 watts minimum, and 15 watts is allowed before needing to support USB-PD for more power.  USB 2.0 hosts are required to supply 2.5 watts minimum.  Over time the USB spec allowed for more power with hosts commonly offering 1.5 amps (or 7.5 watts) by USB-A as devices started to desire more power.

Comment: " Also, what about the adapter is in violation of the specs? Is it not allowed to make USB-C/female to USB-A/male adapters? "  That's right, that kind of adapter is not allowed in the spec.  " There are USB-C/male to USB-A/male cables, and USB-C/male to USB-C/male cables, so why not an adapter that can change from one to the other? "  That's complicated, and not something that can be answered easily.  I can speculate on why but the real answer can only come from the people that wrote the spec.

Comment: OK, I see. Thanks! I guess I was mislead by the mixup of USB-C and the recommendation to buy their USB-C PD adapter. That's marketing for you! Also I can find tons of USB-C/F to USB-A/M adapters online, so, yeah... Interesting though, I'd like to find out more about it.